# How can I fill whole free place in a column with a children widget with required size property?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an UI in Flutter that has a simple circular chart with some text.

This circular chart (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_circular_chart) has a **required** size property. So, we must define its size, but in this way it won't be responsive for all UI screen sizes, it does not fit the whole space I'd like to.

So, e.g. I'd like to set its size to also cover the space annotated with blue:
[image]

Is it possible to set its size dynamically to fit whole free space in the column?

I tried expaned, fittedbox with double.infinity size parames etc. but neither of them helped.

My code:

```
Widget _buildChart() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedCircularChart(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
              key: _chartKey,
              size: const Size(140.0, 140.0),
              chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
              percentageValues: true,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildText(
                    '${AppLocalizations.of(context).localize("free")}: $freeCount',
                    Colors.white),
                _buildText(
                    '${AppLocalizations.of(context).localize("busy")}: $busyCount',
                    Theme.of(context).buttonColor),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Would you be so kind to help me to solve this? How can I make its size responsive? Is it possible at all?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are looking to do here. your current code expands the green container to take up the remaining space. what exactly you want .?

Comment: No, it does not expand, if U see it on a bigger screen, it has a bigger free space under the chart, as the chart does not expand.

Comment: @Tom ring being circular in shape can't stretch its height to fill remaining space in bigger screen. Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `AnimatedCircularChart` in `FittedBox` which is further wrapped in `Expanded` and you don't have to deal with `Size` anymore. No matter what size you provide, it will always give you the maximum space left.

```
Expanded( // add this 
   child: FittedBox( // and  add this 
     child: AnimatedCircularChart(
       key: Key("chart_key"),
       duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
       size: Size(1, 1), // no matter even if it is 1, it will take up all remaining space 
       chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
       percentageValues: true,
       initialChartData: data,
     ),
   ),
 )
```

---

Full code:

```
Widget _buildChart() {
  return Expanded(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(  // add this
            child: FittedBox(  // and  add this
              child: AnimatedCircularChart(
                key: Key("chart_key"),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                size: Size(1, 1), // no matter even if it is 1, it will take up all remaining space
                chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
                percentageValues: true,
                initialChartData: data,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Free: 14"),
              Text("Busy: 31"),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

**Update**:

If you are talking about the remaining space above the ring on bigger screen, then it is because of the ring ability to **remain circular in shape**, so it can't really go beyond that. I have created a small video recording to show you the effect. And I have used `size: 1`.

[image]

Comment: FittedBox was the key thing I have missed. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to hear you found it useful :)

Comment: As interesting as it can be, this is more of a hack than anything.

Comment: @Remi I am not sure if you have ever used the given plugin, otherwise you won't have said "hack"

Answer (score -1):

Use the [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) class for that.
The layoutbuilder class allows you to give a defined height depending on the parent widget constraints. For example you could say that the chart height is 40% of the available height of the parant widget.

For further responsiveness (screen rotation etc.) check out [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

Comment: May I ask where the downvotes are coming from?
Is it because I didn't post the code to solve his problem?

Comment: Hello, I really appriciate your answer, thanks to try to help me! I don't have 2 downvotes as well :)